# Как унать какой google-service.json применяется к билду

Tags: android, gradle, google-services

У меня в приложении есть большое количество `flavor`-ов с разными `dimension` и `matchingFallbacks`. И при сборке проекта, порой бывает очень сложно понять из папки какого `flavor`-а будет браться `google-service.json`.

В случае если его вообще нету в приложении - AS выдает сообщения такого рода

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
C:\Users\username\Desktop\HelloWorld\app\src\devSuffixYes_EnvQaApistaging_\google-services.json
```

Но в случаях когда он есть - не понятно как понять, какой из всех применился к данной сборке.

**Вопрос:** если ли какие то способы, что бы в момент сборки понимать из какой папки были взяты `google-service.json`.

Comment: app.build.generated.res.google-services.debug.values.values.xml